# Converting nested lists of data into multidimensional Numpy arrays

Tags: python, list, numpy, slice

In the code below I am building data up in a nested list.  After the for loop what I would like is to cast it into a multidimensional Numpy array as neatly as possible.  However, when I do the array conversion on it, it only seems to convert the outer list into an array.  Even worse when I continue downward I wind up with dataPoints as shape `(100L,)`...so an array of lists where each list is my data (obviously I wanted a `(100,3)`).  I have tried fooling with `numpy.asanyarray()` also but I can't seem to work it out.  I would really like a 3d array from my 3d list from the outset if that is possible.  If not, how can I get the array of lists into a 2d array without having to iterate and convert them all?

Edit:  I am also open to better way of structuring the data from the outset if it makes processing easier.  However, it is coming over a serial port and the size is not known beforehand.

```
import numpy as np
import time

data = []
for _i in range(100):   #build some list of lists
    d = [np.random.rand(), np.random.rand(), np.random.rand()]
    data.append([d,time.clock()])

dataArray = np.array(data)  #now I have an array of lists of a list(of data) and a time
dataPoints = dataArray[:,0] #this is the data in an array of lists
```

Comment: You don't have a 3d nested list, you have a mix of lists and scalars. data is a list that contains objects that look like this: [[0.434,0.34,0.22],0.2]. That is a mixed object so numpy wouldn't know what to do with it.

Comment: This is true of the original data object, which is why I wasn't sure it was possible from there.  However the dataPoints object is an array of lists of floats which I can't seem to get into a 2d array either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

dataPoints is not a 2d list. Convert it first into a 2d list and then it will work:

```
d=np.array(dataPoints.tolist())
```

Now d is (100,3) as you wanted.

Comment: Yes, dataPoints is an array of lists.  This does work, is it the best way from after the for loop forward?  I wind up converting to array(for the slicing ability), back to list (to get the right shape), then back to array.

Comment: Skip the array conversion and slicing. Append only d (leave time.clock() out, since you are slicing it out later). This will give you a list of lists which you can then convert into an array. Or, better yet, start with a numpy array in the first place and don't use lists.

Comment: I need the timestamp in other parts of the code, and I don't know the size at the time/the data trickles in over a serial port.  But your solution is the best I've found so far.

Comment: @MattAnderson Why aren't you just appending the timestamp to the the number triplet so you get a (100,4) array? What dimensions would you want your final array to be?

Comment: I guess because that would be too simple.  Probably just because in my mind one was a time and one was data, I didn't consider that time in this case is just another data.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

If a 2d array is what you want:

```
from itertools import chain
dataArray = np.array(list(chain(*data)),shape=(100,3))
```

I didn't work out the code so you may have to change the column/row ordering to get the shape to match.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, it is just iterating through and doing an np.array() on each list.  I guess I just feel like there is some better way, if it turns out there isn't I will accept this.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html  I am not sure where you are getting the shape param from.